# Simple Apache Camel SNMP trap

Tags: java, apache-camel, snmp, snmp-trap

I am new to Apache Camel and trying to receive a simple SNMP trap.

I have the Maven project set up with camel-core and org.apache.servicemix.bundles.snmp4j.

I have not been able to find any SNMP examples, but based on other examples I have come up with this Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static Processor myProcessor = new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
            // save to database
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addComponent("snmp", new SnmpComponent());

        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("snmp:127.0.0.1:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP").process(myProcessor);
            }
        };

        try {
            context.addRoutes(builder);
            context.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

However when I run it in Eclipse as Java application it just exits after running for half a second. I was expecting it to keep running and listening to 127.0.0.1:162 ...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to at least pick up a trap and print to System.out is like so:

```
public class SNMPTrap {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SNMPTrap snmpTrap = new SNMPTrap();
        snmpTrap.boot();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void boot() throws Exception {

        main = new Main();
        main.bind("snmp", new SnmpComponent());
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
        main.addMainListener(new Events());

        System.out.println("Starting SNMPTrap. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }

    private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("snmp:127.0.0.1:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP").process(myProcessor)
                .bean("snmp");
        }
    }

    public static Processor myProcessor = new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange trap) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(trap.getIn().getBody(String.class));

            // Save to DB or do other good stuff
        }
    };

    public static class Events extends MainListenerSupport {

        @Override
        public void afterStart(MainSupport main) {
            System.out.println("SNMPTrap is now started!");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeStop(MainSupport main) {
            System.out.println("SNMPTrap is now being stopped!");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get warning that Main which is part of Camel core is deprecated now.