# How to capture SNMP traps in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, snmp

**Senario:**

I am working on a web application using spring boot which captures the SNMP traps generated by an SNMP-enabled device.

**Help wanted:**

A simple example in spring boot where the application can receive SNMP traps.

Comment: Camel is an integration framework. Kafka is a message broker. I don't think either does what you want. More specifically, Camel can (optionally) be used to write _any data_ to Kafka, not just "SNMP traps", so it is not one or the other... Please share what research suggests otherwise

Comment: Well, there are some links which suggests that Camel can be used fro this purpose https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/snmp-component.html, also this question answer on StackOverflow gives some hints regarding that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860982/simple-apache-camel-snmp-trap

Comment: I would love to have suggestions from you regarding this problem apart from Kafka and camel is there anything that can be used for this problem? @OneCricketeer

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with Kafka. Camel itself depends on another library - https://www.snmp4j.org/

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking for some hints.

Use *snmp4j* java library for *trap-receiving and sending* purposes.

[Click here for documentation](https://www.snmp4j.org/)